# div refresh is not properly working with ie8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to get content in div from another page every 1 sec using jquery it work well in firefox but conflict with ie8 
problem is that it is not getting content  after every 1 second

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#load_tweets').load('home_add_img.php?v=1').fadeIn("slow");
}, 1000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
</script>
<div id="load_tweets" style="width:100px; height:200px;"> 
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried running your script when the document is loaded? `$(document).ready(function() { /*your code*/ });`

Answer (score 0):

wrap it inside $(document).ready(); it may work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var auto_refresh = setInterval(function (){
 $('#load_tweets').load('home_add_img.php?v=1').fadeIn("slow");
 }, 1000);
});
```

JavaScript provides the load event for executing code when a page is loaded completely, this event does not get triggered until all content of the page is rendered into DOM. so using document.ready is always best practice.

Comment: i saw ur comment. i agree ur genius than me, there s no second word :P

Comment: "Genius! I wonder how you came up with that" - either thru your comment or through the jQuery documentation...